# Tcl comments: why interpret comments?

Tags: scripting, language-agnostic, tcl, interpreter

In Tclers wiki page, at ['Dodeklogue'](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10259) it is mentioned about comments:

> **Comments**: 
>       If # appears where a command is expected, the rest of the line is a comment. No command execution is attempted, and no characters in the
>   line are interpreted, except that the terminating newline may be
>   escaped with \, signifying that the comment continues on the
>   subsequent line.

However, it seems that comments are interpreted byond the terminal `\`: for example, let the content of file test.tcl be as below:

```
proc test {} {
    # Open brace {
    puts "I am fine"
}

test
```

t

Then
`tclsh test.tcl` gives the following error message:

```
missing close-brace: possible unbalanced brace in comment
    while executing
"proc test {} {"
    (file "hello.tcl" line 1)
Even more interesting
```

Even more interesting, when the open brace `{` is replaced with close brace `}`, the error message is completely different.

Why does Tcl interpreter try to make sense of what is there in a comment, what would we lose if the  Tcl interpretor (or any interpretor in general) was designed to take comments as real comments: once you see `#` completely ignore until the new line (except, check last character of comment if it is `\`) ?

Comment: If comment behavior were to change, what would you expect to happen with this line: `proc foo {} { # do nothing }`? Do you think the closing brace should be part of the comment (thus requiring a closing brace on the next line), or do you think it should end the proc definition?

Comment: If inline comments were allowed I would like the first option to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tcl, unlike a number of other languages, processes comments at the same time as the rest of its syntax. This means that, because it came across a `{` first (as part of the `proc` command invocation) it is focusing on matching up the braces. It only comprehends a `#` as a comment when it is *evaluating* the procedure (i.e., you call the command defined by the `proc` command).

These will work as comments:

```
proc commentDemonstration {} {
    puts "A"
    # if [exit] {
        puts "B"
    # } else [exit]
    puts "C"
}
# Call it and see, _no_ early exit
commentDemonstration
```

They are genuinely comments. It's just that you must balance (or backslash-quote) the braces in a procedure definition (unless you're mad enough to define a procedure body inside double quotes or something; ***don't do that*** for your own sanity's sake) independently of what comments you use. Most of the time you don't notice the balancing requirement, but this is one case where it matters.

---

Being able to put `#` inside things like that is a key to embedding other languages inside Tcl. For example, Critcl allows C source code to be embedded within Tcl, and `#` means something totally different in C.

Comment: In light of this answer, is the comment I quoted from Tclers wiki page, specially the part " and no characters in the line are interpreted, except ..." correct?

Comment: @DurgaDatta: yes, the text you quoted is correct. Note that there are two different interpretation "passes" here. In the first, the invocation of the `proc` command is interpreted. During that "pass", the `#` has no special meaning: it's just text. The interpretation goes `proc` `test` `{}` `{...{...}` (text portions in the third argument are compacted to ellipses here) and finds an imbalance of braces. When interpreting the first line inside the procedure body, the `#` becomes significant and prevents interpretation of the following characters, but by then the imbalance already exists.

Comment: @DurgaDatta: note that I'm using the term "pass" very lightly here: there is a second "pass" only because the contents of the third argument to `proc` are evaluated as a script when the command is invoked. As such, Tcl interpretation is strictly one-pass.